# Will GitHub delete past organization news feed items on a repository if it is deleted?

Tags: github

If an organization deletes a GitHub repository, are the prior public news-feed items relating to that repository also deleted?

Answer (score 1):

I believe so. I've deleted repositories before and past feed items still seem to be on my news feed.